# Regular expression for email id to avoid email input in a textfield

Tags: javascript, html, regex

**Problem**: I am having a textarea in which I want to restrict users from entering their email id. So,that when they type email id the text area should turn red and pop-up a message saying "you can't enter your email address in this field".

**My solution:** Here is the simple HTML code for textarea:

```
<textarea class="replyToClient" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
```

I am currently using the below mentioned javascript code to detect email id and replace it with NULL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //EMAIL ID DETECTION AND REPLACEMNET
        $(function() {
            $(".replyToClient").change(function() {
                $(this).val( function(idx, val) {
                    return val.replace(/\b(\w)+\@(\w)+\.(\w)+\b/g, "");
                });
            });
        });

        </script>
```

What this does is replaces something like "example@gmail.com" written in textarea with blank.

**Expectation:** I am trying to build a strong regexp here so that I can detect email id in any form such as "example@gmail" or "example at the rate gmail dot com" and then (the easy part)replace it from the textarea or come up with a pop-up.

So, my concern is mainly on the regular expression to detect email id in it's original format and also in the possible broken formats as mentioned above.

Comment: Just a side note: doing that on the client side will not be sufficient, because anyone with a bit of javascript skills will be able to avoid such control, so you should check that first on the client and, later, on the server too.

Comment: Something else came to my mind after reading the question and @briosheje 's comment. If this is a critical application, e.g. you don't want users to tell contact details to each other (maybe commercial or security reasons as in dating sites), you'll have to train a classifier model (yeah Machine Learning and Data Science stuff) to find if the string contains personal contact information or not. I can present so many variations that any regular expression can fail very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of update to Roberts answer. The regex shown does not process dashes, underscores and dots are not taken accout for, which are standard for e-mails, as well as england based e-mails (.co.uk)

This is important for the first word. `john-wick@gmail.com` and `john-wick at gmail dot com` will respectively result in `wick@gmail.com` and `wick at gmail dot com`, leaving unwanted words in your text area. Try:

```
[A-Za-z0-9.\-\_]*?@\w+(\.\w+)?(\.\w+)?|[A-Za-z0-9.\-\_]*? at \w+ dot \w+( dot \w+)?
```

The regex seems to work for all the mentioned possibilities as `john-wick@gmail.com`, `john-wick at gmail dot com` and `john-wick@example.co.uk`, `john-wick at example dot co dot uk`.

If there are other broken formats people tend to write their e-mails, they should probably be dealt with one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

give this a shot:

```
val.replace(/\w+@\w+(\.\w+)?|\w+ at \w+ dot \w+/ig, "");
```

Cheers